# Append child divs to each instance of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div (rateRibbon) that I'm adding to random number of **parent** divs, that will require four child divs to be appended each time the parent (rateRibbon) exists.

```
<div class="ratesListing roomsView">
    <div class="rateTypeLineItems"></div>
</div>

<div class="ratesListing roomsView">
    <div class="rateTypeLineItems"></div>
</div>
```

1. Rather than adding four child divs to each parent, how can I loop through until it gets to 4, and then stop?
2. How do I get each new (rateRibbon), with its 4 children, to append to each rateTypeLineItems?

Here's my JQuery:

```
//prepend rate ribbon at the top of each room rate type
$('.rateTypeLineItems').prepend('<div class="rateRibbon"> <!-- this is a container div --> </div>');

//prepend messaging container into rate ribbon
$('.rateRibbon').prepend('<div class="posMsg"></div><div class="posMsg"></div><div class="posMsg"></div><div class="posMsg"></div>');

//append messaging content every time "rateRibbon" loads
$('.rateRibbon:eq(0)').each(function (i) {
    $('.posMsg:eq(0)').append('<h3>Best Price Guarantee</h3><p>Get the lowest price for our hotels. We Guarantee it.</p>');
    $('.posMsg:eq(1)').append('<h3>IHG Rewards Club</h3><p>Be part of the world’s best hotel rewards program.</p>');
    $('.posMsg:eq(2)').append('<h3>A Guaranteed Room</h3><p>Book directly with IHG to guarantee your room.</p>');
    $('.posMsg:eq(3)').append('<h3>No Booking Fees</h3><p>There are no hidden booking fees when booking direct.</p>');
});
```

And a link to my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkmills1/BwLm6/1/).

Comment: Some advice: use functions. They'll make your life a whole lot easier if you're dealing with blocks of code.

Comment: You might simplify your question to just what you're having trouble with. It's a bit hard to follow. Show only the HTML as it appears during the problem, and only the relevant jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store each of your messages in a variable and incorporate them into the inclusion of the .rateRibbon so it happens all at once and you're not having to query the DOM so much.

Here's the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/x8VE5/

The key portion of the modified script:

```
var msg1 = '<h3>Best Price Guarantee</h3><p>Get the lowest price for our hotels. We Guarantee it.</p>';
var msg2 = '<h3>IHG Rewards Club</h3><p>Be part of the world’s best hotel rewards program.</p>';
var msg3 = '<h3>A Guaranteed Room</h3><p>Book directly with IHG to guarantee your room.</p>';
var msg4 = '<h3>No Booking Fees</h3><p>There are no hidden booking fees when booking direct.</p>';

//prepend messaging container into rate ribbon
//var rateRibbon = '<div class="posMsg"></div>';
$('.rateRibbon').prepend('<div class="posMsg">'+msg1+'</div><div class="posMsg">'+msg2+'</div><div class="posMsg">'+msg3+'</div><div class="posMsg">'+msg4+'</div>');
```

Comment: Oh yeah!!! That's it! 

I'm at a new gig, and encounter this scenario often. I'll be sure to save and reuse this as much as possible. Though I'm sure I'll come to understand it after some time.

Thanks, redlena!!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to clean this up, but start with the basics by looping through each rate ribbon -

```
$('.rateRibbon').each(function (i) {
    $(this).prepend('<div class="posMsg"></div><div class="posMsg"></div><div class="posMsg"></div><div class="posMsg"></div>');
    $(this).find('.posMsg:eq(0)').append('<h3>Best Price Guarantee</h3><p>Get the lowest price for our hotels. We Guarantee it.</p>');
    $(this).find('.posMsg:eq(1)').append('<h3>IHG Rewards Club</h3><p>Be part of the world’s best hotel rewards program.</p>');
    $(this).find('.posMsg:eq(2)').append('<h3>A Guaranteed Room</h3><p>Book directly with IHG to guarantee your room.</p>');
    $(this).find('.posMsg:eq(3)').append('<h3>No Booking Fees</h3><p>There are no hidden booking fees when booking direct.</p>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/W25dw/1/

Of course your code could be further enhanced, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Jay! This is a solid solution as well. I'll be sure to keep and use it in the future.